# Nginx subdirectory root PHP with Rails or Django app

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I'm trying to add a PHP app in subdirectory with different root location.

For example, I have a Rails app at root `/` and I want to add a phpBB forum at `/forum` location.

**I also have a specific need:** I want to add a rewrite rule for a file located in forum root directory (e.g. rewrite /forum/foo.php to /forum/bar.php)

I tried multiple configurations with some examples given on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work :(

If there is no solution I will use subdomain instead (e.g. forum.domain.com), but I would like to try with only one domain if possible

```
upstream railsApp {
  server unix:/tmp/puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /var/www/domain.com/railsApp/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/domain.com/privkey.pem;

  client_body_buffer_size 10M;
  client_max_body_size 10M;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://railsApp;
  }

  # Here I want a PHP app with different root location
  # forum is an example
  location /forum {
    root /var/www/other-location;
    index index.html index.php;

    include proxy_params;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # I also want to add rewrite rule for a specific file name
    location ~ /foo {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /bar.php$1 last;
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is everything other except the rewrite rule works as expected?

Comment: Your configuration placed the PHP application in `/var/www/other-location/forum`. Is that correct? Or is it in `/var/www/other-location`?

Comment: Hello, sorry I gave the forum as an example because I though it was easier for me to explain (I'm not english speaker), but in fact it is a php file to call at a particular location: I'm using matomo tracker proxy.

instead of `location /forum` it is `location /matomo`

I changed `root /var/www/tracker-proxy` to `alias /var/www/tracker-proxy` 
and I added `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args =404;`

Everything work except the rewrite rule.